# Why does sodium sulfate have an unusual solubility-temperature curve?

Tags: solubility

For many salts there are solubility curves as a function of temperature that are smooth (don't have any kinks). Sodium sulfate, however, has a kink in the solubility-T curve at 30 degrees as shown below:

[image]

What happens when the temperature is about 30 degree?

Answer (score 10):

"Sodium sulfate" is a mixture of hydrated phases in shifting equilibrium given temperature and concentration.

[image: Na2SO4.(H2O)x phase diagram, 1]
[image: Na2SO4.(H2O)x phase diagram, 2]

Answer (score 3):

The phase diagram is also interesting here.  Notice the convergence of three lines at about 30C and 30 wt% NaSO4, right near where the kink in the solubility happens.

[image]

Comment: Do you still remember the source where you got this phase diagram?

Comment: No, sorry.  Wish I had cited it.

Comment: In case anyone needs it: the figure is from [Angeli _et al._, 2010](https://sp.lyellcollection.org/content/333/1/35) [1], adapted from Hougen _et al._, 1954 [2].

[1]M. Angeli, R. Hébert, B. Menéndez, C. David, and J.-P. Bigas, ‘Influence of temperature and salt concentration on the salt weathering of a sedimentary stone with sodium sulphate’, Geological Society, London, _Special Publications_, vol. 333, no. 1, pp. 35–42, Jan. 2010.
[2]O. A. Hougen, K. W. Watson, and R. A. Ragatz, _Chemical Process Principles. Part I_. 2nd edn. Wiley, New York, 1954.