# Why is solubility affected by temperature?

Tags: inorganic-chemistry, quantum-chemistry, solutions

Why when we raise temperature  generally  a bigger concentration of a  soluble gets dissolved in a inorganic solvent?Is there a quantum mechanical reason why this is happening?

Comment: Quantum mechanical? That's just basic thermodynamics.

Comment: @Mithoron explain please.I never really understood it.

Comment: Just analyse how Gibbs energy of dissolving changes with temp.

Comment: https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/21855/why-do-some-solid-chemicals-dissolve-better-in-colder-water

Comment: Dissolution requires energy changes, which is temperature related.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Firstly that is strictly not true. Most solutes that are gaseous at the temperature will be less solvated the higher the temperature of the solvent liquid, for instance. There are other relevant examples as well.

Secondly, if you do not understand this, there is no reason to go digging into quantum chemistry. That is a game best left alone untill you are good and ready.

The most reasonable way to understand this is through understanding energy and thermodynamics. Most substances solvation are favorable to increasing temperature in terms of enthalpy. Energy is required to break the bonds of the pure sample, energy is required to displace solvent-solvent bonds and energy is gained from forming solvent-solute bonds. With temperature all these enthalpies change in magnitude. There is also entropy, the entropy of mixing - which is a strong contributor to increased solvation at elevated temperatures.